# How to query from Mysql DATETIME column based on day name

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a `DATETIME` column in MySql Table column.Now as per my requirement i have to get the records from the last `Tuesday` to current `Tuesday`.Is it possible.If yes ,Please tell me how .

Thanks in advance..

Comment: is the tuesday a fixed day of the week or just because its tuesday today?

Comment: do you want to include both tuesdays? just the first tuesday? just the last tuesday?  this in an inclusive/exclusive question, but pretty relevant. I think you could use DATE_SUB combined with DAYOFWEEK to subtract from NOW() and get previous tuesday.

Comment: @Markus It can be any day.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Suppose if today is tuesday i want records between  todays and last tuesday

Comment: Please have a look at the functions MySQL provides [for this matter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). I'm pretty sure you can best figure it out yourself, as your question is unclear.

Comment: Your requirement is to get past week record right?

Comment: May i know why i have been down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE `date` > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: what if today is wednesday and he want result from yesterday to prev tuesday